Fetch Telegram API in Google Cloud VM Instance is Failed
So, i want to send Telegram API Bot in Google Cloud VM Instance using Ubuntu latest version or the highest version. I'm using NodeJS program and fetch to run the API.
But i got this error:
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13185:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async exports.sendMessage (/root/anonymous/controller/telegram/sendMessageController.js:19:21) {
  [cause]: AggregateError [ETIMEDOUT]: 
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1117:18)
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1185:5)
      at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1711:5)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:596:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:529:7) {
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  }
}

This my code (sendMessageController.js) :
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

exports.sendMessage = async (req, res) => {
  const { message } = req.body;

  if (!req.body || Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: 400,
      message: "Bad request",
    });
  }

  try {
    const token = process.env.TELEGRAM_TOKEN;
    const url = process.env.TELEGRAM_API_URL;
    const channel = process.env.TELEGRAM_CHANNEL_ID;
    const request = await fetch(`${url}/bot${token}/sendMessage`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        chat_id: channel,
        text: message.replace(/[_*[\]()~`>#+-=|{}.!-]/g, "\\$&"),
        parse_mode: "MarkdownV2",
      }),
    });

    const response = await request.json();

    console.log(response);
    res.status(200).json({ status: 200, message: "Success", data: response });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ status: 500, message: "Internal server error" });
  }
};

I'm triggering using REST API, the issue is from this code.
What I expect is the fetch is working, nothing failed like in Localhost.

what do you think ETIMEDOUT means?

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72149120/google-cloud-compute-engine-http-connection-timeout

You include insufficient information for us to help. If you grab the URL generated by your code, can you effect the call successfully using e.g. curl from a shell on the VM? If not, per @dan-macak, it's likely your VM isn't correctly configured to permit the egress traffic.

Well, i already tried curl Telegram API link and the output is 302 Found.

Time out from the connection @Jaromanda X

302 found ... curl doesn't follow redirects, which is what a 302 is, try curl with -L flag

Well, i don't see any status code, but it seems there's a bunch of code of api.telegram.org page site. But i don't think that solve any @Jaramanda X

Well, apparently i have to add after body
const request = await fetch(`${url}/bot${token}/sendMessage`, {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     chat_id: channel,
     text: message.replace(/[_*[\]()~`>#+-=|{}.!-]/g, "\\$&"),
     parse_mode: "MarkdownV2",
   },
   {
     family: 4,
   }
  ),
 }
);

The code is working, but is it safe?
